# Storyboard fields(Labels/buttons and etc..,) are not appearing

Tags: ios, swift

I am developing a new project with using swift
[image]

I added some fields on Yesterday in UITableviewCell, but Today i re opend the project but all fields are in hidden mode --> I checked wether those are in hidden or not but all are not selected in Hidden button in project details panel

Can you please help me out..

Answer (score 1):

can you see `wAny hAny` at the bottom of your screen?

Change that to whatever you were using before while adding the labels and buttons.

Size-classes feature are used to display/modify elements according to particular view type.

Answer (score 1):

Guess its the size class that you need to work on

Answer (score 0):

It means your label in other size class.

Change your size class. Do you see: "wAny hAny"?. Try to play with them.

Ref: http://swiftiostutorials.com/using-size-classes-xcode-6/